# installing VSTS agent on Ubuntu Server ARM64

Tags: ubuntu, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, arm64

I am trying to install azagent on ubuntu arm64 server so that release pipeline can push artifacts to server's file system.
I downloaded latest release from below link.
https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.217.2/vsts-agent-linux-arm64-2.217.2.tar.gz
When I run config.sh I get below error.
`The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.`

*Note that I tried running installdependencies.sh but it fails with below error*

```
E: Unable to locate package liblttng-ust0
```

**output after running config.sh**

```
./bin/System.Net.Http.Native.so: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by ./bin/System.Net.Http.Native.so)
Warning: on some platforms, libcurl3 is required.
It was not found.
Execute ./bin/installdependencies.sh to install missing dependencies.

  ___                      ______ _            _ _
 / _ \                     | ___ (_)          | (_)
/ /_\ \_____   _ _ __ ___  | |_/ /_ _ __   ___| |_ _ __   ___  ___
|  _  |_  / | | | '__/ _ \ |  __/| | '_ \ / _ \ | | '_ \ / _ \/ __|
| | | |/ /| |_| | | |  __/ | |   | | |_) |  __/ | | | | |  __/\__ \
\_| |_/___|\__,_|_|  \___| \_|   |_| .__/ \___|_|_|_| |_|\___||___/
                                   | |
        agent v2.217.2             |_|          (commit ef0b5a5)


>> End User License Agreements:

Building sources from a TFVC repository requires accepting the Team Explorer Everywhere End User License Agreement. This step is not required for building sources from Git repositories.

A copy of the Team Explorer Everywhere license agreement can be found at:
  /home/ubuntu/vstsagebt/license.html

Enter (Y/N) Accept the Team Explorer Everywhere license agreement now? (press enter for N) > Y

>> Connect:

Enter server URL > https://**************.visualstudio.com 
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) > 
Enter personal access token > ****************************************************
Error reported in diagnostic logs. Please examine the log for more details.
    - /home/ubuntu/vstsagebt/_diag/Agent_20230217-043447-utc.log
The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL >
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @jessehouwing  Thanks.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Ubuntu the dependency has been renamed and the installer scripts have been updated to use this new package name.

You haven't mentioned your Ubuntu version, but you may finds hint on how to resolve your problem in this issue:

- https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1584#issuecomment-1161955604

Try manually running

```
sudo apt-get install liblttng-ust1
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Comment: Updated above...